# How do I delete a row in a UITableView where the var is an integer?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, delete-row

I'm creating an audio voice recorder and after each upload, the name appends an int to the recording (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc.) in a table view (note: regular view controller with a UITableView vs. Table View Controller).

I'm having trouble deleting each row, and I'm not sure if it is because 'numberOfRecords.remove(at: indexPath.row)' only accepts strings.

I get the error: "Value of type 'Int' has no member 'remove.'"

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, RecordButtonDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var numberOfRecords : Int = 0

// Setting up Table View
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numberOfRecords
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")

    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    catch {

    }
}

// Delete rows
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        numberOfRecords.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

    }
}


// Audio Player
var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
var recordingSession : AVAudioSession!
var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!
var recordButton: RecordButton?

@IBOutlet weak var buttonLabel2: RecordButton!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    buttonLabel2.delegate = self

}

func tapButton(isRecording: Bool) {

    // Check if we have an active recorder
    if audioRecorder == nil {
        numberOfRecords += 1
        let filename = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(numberOfRecords).m4a")

        let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                        AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
                        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]

        // Start audio recording
        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: filename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.record()

        }

        catch {
            displayAlert(title: "Oops!", message: "Recording failed")
        }

        // Play speaker instead of earpiece
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do {
            try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Audio Session error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }


    }
    else {
        // Stop audio recording
        audioRecorder.stop()
        audioRecorder = nil

        UserDefaults.standard.set(numberOfRecords, forKey: "myNumber")
        myTableView.reloadData()

    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setting up Recording session
    recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    if let number : Int = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myNumber") as? Int {
        numberOfRecords = number
    }

    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission { (hasPermission) in
        if hasPermission {
            print ("Accepted")
        }
    }
```

Comment: `numberOfRecords -= 1`?  Or if you need to track more data than just the count, you should be using an array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you're experiencing is due you calling `remove(at:)` on an Int. An Int has no function called `remove(at:)`.

You're declaring `var numberOfRecords: Int` to track your indices, then in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

you're calling

```
// this is the line that's causing your problem
numberOfRecords.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

If you want to continue using an int to track your cells you should subtract from `numberOfRecords`

```
numberOfRecords-=1
```

Or you could track your records using an array something like this:

```
// declare an array of Strings to hold your filenames
var records: [String] = []
```

then where you're saving your files add the new filename to your array for the tableview

```
// Stop audio recording
audioRecorder.stop()
audioRecorder = nil

// add your filename to your array of records for the tableview
records.append(filename)

// update your total number of records if desired
UserDefaults.standard.set(numberOfRecords, forKey: "myNumber")
myTableView.reloadData()
```

Then your delegate functions might look something like this

```
// Setting up Table View
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // return the total count of filenames in your array
    return records.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    // set the filename in your text label
    cell.textLabel?.text = records[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // get the filename for this row
    let filename = records[indexPath.row]

    // use your filename in your path
    let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(filename)")

    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    catch {

    }
}
```

and you could update your `remove(at:)` call to run on the records array instead

```
records.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

EDIT:

When you add or remove filenames from your records array update user defaults with your updated records:

```
// save array to user defaults when you create a new record or when you delete a record
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(records, forKey: "storedRecords")
```

To retrieve your saved array of filenames pull them from user defaults and update your records array with the stored names.

Replace these lines in your `viewDidLoad` function:

```
if let number : Int = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myNumber") as? Int {
    numberOfRecords = number
}
```

with this:

```
// load stored records from user defaults and verify it's what you expect to receive
if let stored = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "storedRecords") as? [String] {
    // update your records array with the stored values
    records = stored
}
```

Comment: Thanks @digitalHound! I'm now able to delete the row with the suggested array change; however, my historical list of recordings is no longer preserved in the TableView at launch. Have I made an error in the above implementation?

`  var records: [String] = []
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = records[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
`

Comment: edited answer with additional info for persisting your array of filenames